# Handle ambiguous map

Tags: key-bindings

I can make a map like this:

```
nmap wr :write<CR>
```

but then it clashes with another map:

- http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#map-ambiguous
- http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#w

So if I do press `w`, it pauses before performing the motion. How can I quickly
perform the `w` motion? I tried `ww`, but then it motions twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use capital instead:

```
nmap W :write<CR>
```

This will likely clobber something else (as in this case), but usually the
capitals are less used than lowercase. Another option is `abbreviate`:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:abbreviate

Example:

```
abbrev w write
```

This avoids the ambiguous map, as the example above only works in command mode.
Drawback is that is take more keys, as its `Shift : w Enter`, instead of just
`w r`. Also in this case its redundant as you can already use `w` instead of
`write`. However I found this useful for other cases.

Comment: Problem with a simple abbreviation like that is that it's expanded in way more contexts than you expect... You can use `:cabbrev` to make it only work in command-line (and search, and input...) But it's still a problem, for instance try opening or saving a file named `w.txt` with that abbreviation... You can work around that, but you typically need an `<expr>` mapping checking you're in command-line with `getcmdtype()` and use `getcmdpos()` to check it's the first word in the line (only expand as the "command", not in arguments.)

Answer (score 2):

In order to trigger the mapping before [`'timeoutlen'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27timeoutlen%27) expires you can hit any other key that will not have a side effect and work as a null operation.

In this case, in Normal mode, you can use `<Esc>`, which does nothing if you're already in Normal mode. So you could use `w<Esc>` to have the `w` motion applied right away.

(Of course, the best solution is to avoid such mappings in first place, mappings such as `wr` which shadow useful commands such as the `w` motion. Prefer to put your mappings under a [`<Leader>`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#mapleader) prefix to have them in a separate namespace outside of the regular Vim commands.)